# Finding the coordinates of an orthogonal projection point

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I would like to find the coordinates of point $D$ , given that the length $\overline{AD}$ is $\sqrt{5}$?

[image]

For this, I've already found the $\overset{\longleftrightarrow}{AB}$ line equation, which is $y=-\frac{x}2 + 2$, and the $\overset{\longleftrightarrow}{AD}$ line as well:$y=2x-8$.

How do I find the coordinates of $D$ knowing only these lines' equations and that the distance between $A$ and $D$ is $\sqrt{5}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE, thanks for using MathJax and for showing your work. Both of these will be of help to those trying to help you.

Comment: Alt. hint: $\;AB^2=4^2+2^2=20\,$, so $BD^2 = AB^2+AD^2=20+5=25\,$. The system $DA^2=5\,$, $DB^2=25$ gives two equations to solve for the two unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

$\bf{HINT}$: Let D have co-ordinates $(x_d, y_d)$. Now, these are two equations that these variables must satisfy. (a) $y_d = 2x_d - 8$ and (b) $(x_d - 4)^2 + (y_d - 0)^2 = 5$. You have two equations and two unknowns. You should also be able to eliminate one of the roots of the quadratic equation.